# DataNucleus Enhancer Error

Tags: google-app-engine, datanucleus

I get the below error when I generate google backend, I am a frustrated newbie, please help me :)

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:76)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.(Enhance.java:71)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.main(Enhance.java:51)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:74)
>     ... 2 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>     at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>     at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>     at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(Unknown Source)
>     at >org.datanucleus.enhancer.asm.ASMClassEnhancer.getClassNameForFileName(ASMClassEnhancer.jav>a:272)
>     at >org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.j>ava:727)
>     at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:525)
>     at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1258)
>     ... 7 more

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and you think that by not telling people how you got something is going to get some deep insight into how to fix it? What versions of what jars? what were you doing? how did you invoke it? what version of ASM? why aren't you using v2.x of datanucleus-google plugin?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am so badly newbie that I couldn't even give details. Anyhow, I solved it with using Java version 1.7.